# data insertion in online database from android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

i am trying to insert data from android to online database, my app does not give any error so that i can fix it, it worked fine when i connected my app to localhost and it was inserting data successfully but when i try to insert data to online database it doesn't work. can someone tell me what am doing wrong?
before you have a look at my code i want you to look at my hosting information, in case you guys think am doing something wrong with this.

```
Main Domain securekid.base.pk
FTP hostname:   ftp.base.pk
FTP username:   basep_****
MySQL hostname: sql104.base.pk
MySQL username: basep_****
Hosting Volume  vol14_2
```

my db connection file:

```
<?php
$host = "sql104.base.pk";
$user = "basep_****";
$password = "******";
$db = "basep_*****_android";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
if($con)
{
    echo "successful";
}
else
{
    die("error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
require "db_connect.php";
$username =$_POST["username"];
$password =$_POST["password"];
$phone_no =$_POST["phone_no"];
$mysql_qry = "insert into user(username,password,phone_no) values('$username', '$password', '$phone_no')";

if($con->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE)
{
    echo  "Registration Successful";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}
?>
```

this is background.java file

```
class backgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
   // Globals session_id = Globals.getInstance();
    // Globals session_id_child = Globals.getInstance();
    backgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    String reg_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        reg_url = "http://securekid.base.pk/app/register.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String method = args[0];

        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String username = args[1];
            String password = args[2];
            String phone_no = args[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("phone_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone_no, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Successful";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in code you haven't posted you are checking if the browser supports JavaScript. An Android HttpURLConnection doesn't process JavaScript so your request will fail. The result you will get is this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
            <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("b9a6c9d5cb703e2906de146c3bad1187");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://securekid.base.pk/app/register.php?ckattempt=1";
            </script>
            <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would suggest looking at the part of your site that generates that code and disabling it for your API files since an API client would never be expected to process JavaScript.

Comment: but i have followed a tutorial and it works fine with him

Comment: and i don't have anything on my website, am using the server for database so that i can upload app's data on server nothing else.

Comment: @user3149023 I'm sorry, but you certainly do have other code running. Clear your cookies and then visit the URL `http://securekid.base.pk/app/register.php` yourself in your browser and look at where you end up. You will find you are at `http://securekid.base.pk/app/register.php?ckattempt=1`. Now ask yourself where the code is that generated that redirect.

Comment: yeah i now got your point but i am using free domain, do you have any idea where can i get to disable the javascript?